# How can i solve bugs of my vhdl fifo memory?

Tags: vhdl, fifo, active-hdl

I created a fifo memory in vhdl but i have some problems with it.
To be more exactly i put 16(capacity of memory) elements in my memory but
when i want to read from memory i can just read 14 elements.(My empty signal becomes 1 too early).
Here is the code:
[code](http://www.mediafire.com/file/41wu1rju4b7q1tt/fifo.rar)

Comment: It is customary to put the code IN the question.

Comment: A mention that i forget:I simulated in active-hdl so i did't use clock divider or debouncer

Comment: Your question doesn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: I put code that i wrote (i know it's not minimal but it's pretty hard to put just a piece of code because  i used components and people should now how i connected them - maybe there is the problem) and i said what my problem is by describing it (i give an example in question).Sorry i forget something..Can you help me ?

Comment: Converting some of the variables in the process in STATUS to signals seems worthwhile for waveform troubleshooting. Their equations  look like they originated in a CPLD design (and none of the grouping parentheses are needed). This `a := q(0) and not q(2) and not q(3) and not q(3);` looks erroneous, probably should be `a := q(0) and not q(1) and not q(2) and not q(3);`. That get's all 16 values out of the FIFO.  outdata could also be shifted with a one clock host holdover for issuing pop from EMPTY false by enabling dataout reg all the time in RAM. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: A MCVE doesn't have to be big and elaborate, the problem exists wholly in fifo_status.vhd which generates status flags and operates a counter (c4ud.vhd) specifying the number of items in the FIFO along with the full and empty flip flops (whose outputs aren't signals). You'd only need a testbench that generated ce_wr, ce_rd and clk. Converting variables in the process to signals assigned in concurrent assignment would allow everything to be visible in a waveform display (the problem was actually noted by proof reading).